Как разрешить обработку html в тексте kotlin
Я не силен в kotlin, с сервера приходит json в тексте которого имеется ссылка в виде html, но проблема в том, что она выводится как есть в виде текста. Как заставить kotlin обрабатывать её в виде ссылки html?
$manuals = [
    'ru' => [
        'title'  => 'xxxx',
        'points' => [
            [
                'text' => '<a href="https://google.com/">test123</a>',
                "img"  => "https://test.ru/help/mod1.jpg",
            ],
            [
                'text' => 'textxxxxxxxx',
                "img"  => "https://test.ru/help/mod1.jpg",
            ],
            [
                'text' => 'textxxxxxxxx',
                "img"  => "https://test.ru/help/mod1.jpg",
            ],
        ],
    ],

А вот код в приложении на экране вывода этого текста
@Composable
fun Page(
    manual: Manual?
) {
    val obj: ManualPoints? = Gson().fromJson(manual?.manual, ManualPoints::class.java)

    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp)
    ) {

        if (manual?.manual == null) {
            item {
                CircularProgressIndicator(
                    modifier = Modifier.size(40.dp)
                )
            }
        } else {
            item {
                Text(
                    text = obj?.title ?: "",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(bottom = 0.dp),
                    style = manualH.copy(
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center, color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground
                    ),
                )
            }

            items(obj?.points.orEmpty()) {
                Box {
                    Point(it)
                }

            }

        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Point(point: Point) {
    Column {
        Text(
            text = point.text ?: "",
            style = manual.copy(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(bottom = 5.dp, top = 25.dp),
        )

        if (!point.img.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            Box(modifier = Modifier.border(5.dp, Color(0XFFFFB039))) {
                GlideImage(imageModel = point.img,
                    imageOptions = ImageOptions(contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(10.dp)
                        .fillMaxWidth(),
                    loading = remember {
                        {
                            Box(
                                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                            ) {
                                CircularProgressIndicator()
                            }
                        }
                    })
            }
        }

    }
}


так язык html - это же текст. как можно его обрабатывать «не как текст»?

как заставить выводимый текст поддерживать html? сейчас он выводится просто текстом в виде: "test123" как есть.

то, что вы привели в комментарии - это и есть html. вы, наверно, веб-браузер хотите интегрировать в свою программу.

нет, я хочу чтобы в тексте появилась ссылка, а не текст, а по клику на ссылку открылся браузер по умолчанию на устройстве и собственно загружался этот сайт

ну, да, точно: вы хотите, чтобы ваша программа вела себя как браузер: нарисовала «ссылку» и обработала нажатие на неё.

Ссылку распарсить, получить урл и вывести в ClickableText для которого построить правильный buildAnnotatedString чтобы выглядела как ссылка и по клику открыть браузер используя LocalUriHandler.current. Но вроде ClickableText deprecated и поэтому buildAnnotatedString  (внутри withLink) и обычный Text

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66494838/android-compose-how-to-use-html-tags-in-a-text-view
